# How to get rid of curly braces from expanded list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new to Python, so please bear with me. I'm trying to populate an optionmenu with rows from an SQLite database. The problem is that when a cell contains a space, the option appears with {} around it. What is the proper way to do this?

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('db_name.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''SELECT client_name FROM clients
         ORDER BY client_name''')
clients = c.fetchall()

master = Tk()
variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set("Select Client")
client = OptionMenu(master, variable, *tuple(clients))
```

Comment: What is the result of `tuple(clients)`?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams You mean without the asterisk? Then everything is on one line

Comment: I'm not asking you to *use* it, I'm asking you to *print it out*.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams The different items on one line, separated by spaces, but the one with a space in it surrounded by double curly braces.

Comment: Then fix it in your database, because that's where the problem is.

Comment: When I open the database as plain text I don't see any curly braces.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams Using SQLite Manager in Firefox I also don't see curly braces.

Comment: This definitely sounds like your DB, it's worth checking what characters you actually have in there rather than what you can see (view the byte representation)

Comment: @Ben Actually when I use print() I see (('Client1',), ('Client2',), ('Client 3',)) I thought putting it in a Label would show me the same thing. As I said, beginner here.

Comment: This is printing `tuple(clients)` as the database API returns a list of tuples? That means that this is nothing to do with SQLite and is tkinter (might want to retag). My first search returned: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16119671/458741

Comment: @Ben Thanks. I saw that question but didn't find the answers helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method accepts strings for options, each separated as a positional argument (see [this example](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm) from effbot).

You are actually sending tuples and not strings; because `fetchall()` will return a tuple for each row, and the elements in the tuple represent columns from the result set.

As you are only selecting one column in your query,  your results contain a one-tuple (a tuple with only one element):

```
(('Client1',), ('Client2',), ('Client 3',))
#----------^ this is a single element tuple
```

You need to send to the method:

```
client_list = OptionMenu(master, client, 'Client1', 'Client2', 'Client3')
```

You are actually sending:

```
client_list = OptionMenu(master, client, ('Client1',), ('Client2',), ('Client3',))
```

The reason your fix works is because it collapses the tuple, so instead of a tuple of tuples, its a tuple of strings:

```
>>> clients = (('Client1',), ('Client2',), ('Client 3',))
>>> sum(clients, ())
('Client1', 'Client2', 'Client 3')
```

There is nothing wrong with your fix, and you can implement it another way as well:

```
clients = [i[0] for i in c.fetchall()] # Now you have gotten rid of the
                                       # inner tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to get the similar result.

```
import re
clients = [re.sub('[{}]', '',x) for x in c.fetchall()]
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why, but this works:

```
client_tuple = sum(clients, ())
client_list = OptionMenu(master, client, *client_tuple)
```